# The ± sign in square root

Tags: proof-verification, radicals

As I was doing a SAT question when I came across this question:

$\sqrt {x-a} = x-4$
       If $a=2$,what is the solution set of the equation?

**Options**

- {$3,6$}
- {$2$}
- {$3$}
- {$6$}     Correct Answer

I evaluated the equation and got $0=(x-3)(x-6)$
If you put those number in the equation, you should get:

**For 3:**
$\sqrt {3-2} = 3-4$
Since $\sqrt {1} = ±1$  
$±1 = -1$

**For 6:**
$\sqrt {6-2} = 6-4$
Since $\sqrt {4} = ±2$  
$±2 = 2$

For the answer, they(SAT) evaluated $\sqrt {1}$ as $\sqrt {1} = -1$ and $\sqrt {4}$ as $\sqrt {4} = 2$
 Why is it that $\sqrt {1}$ is equal to $-1$ and not $1$ and why $\sqrt {4}$ is equal to $2$ and not $-2$ Why isn't the solution set {$3,6$} a correct answer?

Comment: This was an equation to solve in real numbers, so the symbol $\sqrt x $ is meant to be the *positive* square root. No $\pm $ - only $+$. Also note your error in case 3: $3-4=-1$, not $1$.

Comment: 3 is *not* a solution precisely because $\sqrt 1\ne-1$. I think "they" must have written $\sqrt 1=-1$ as an obvious contradiction that you reach if you assume 3 is a solution, therefore 3 is not a solution.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By definition $\sqrt{}$ is always the non-negative root.  Every positive number has exactly two square roots equal in magnitude, on positive and one negative.

$\sqrt{25} =5$ and $\sqrt {25} \ne -5$.  But both $5$ and $-5$ are solutions to $x^2 = 25$.

To solve an equation $x^2 = k$ there will be two answers.  One is $\sqrt k$ and $\sqrt k > 0$ and the other is $-\sqrt{k}$ and $-\sqrt {k} < 0$

So if you try to solve an equation by "squaring both sides", you will be changing the equation to allow for two different square roots that were *not* part of the original problem.  This is called superfluous solutions.

So to solve

$\sqrt {x-2} = x- 4$

Is not just to solve $x-2 = (x-4)^2$ but is to *ALSO* solve $x - 4 \ge 0$.

So you did $\sqrt{x-2}^2 = (x-4)^2$.  But that adds in the *negative* solution as well.

$x^2 - 8x + 16 = x-2$ and $x^2 - 9x + 18 = (x-6)(x-3)$ so both of those solve $x-2 = (x-4)^2$ but only one of them solve $\sqrt{x-2} = x-4$. (Because we must have $x-4 \ge 0$.)

$\sqrt{6-2} \overset?= 6-4$

$\sqrt{4} \overset?= 2$

$2 \overset \checkmark = 2$ check.  $6$ is an answer and $6-4 > 0$.

$\sqrt{3-2} \overset?= 3-4$

$\sqrt{1} \overset?= -1$

$1 \ne -1$. No!  $\sqrt{1} = 1$.  $\sqrt{1} \ne -1$.   And $3-2 < 0$.

Comment: Can u explain the `??` ?

Comment: I meant "do they equal"

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense

Comment: Fast way: noticing x−4≥0, the only possibly correct answer is the last one

Comment: I hope writing $\overset?=$ was okay for you. I think the $=?=$ looks strange. I have no idea what $===$ and $=\not==$ stands for. Nice answer otherwise.

Comment: I was hoping =?= was clear in context.  I didn't do $\overset ?=$ because I didn't know the \overset command and researching MathJax for an actual list of commands for a quick markup rather a full extensive manual for global style sheets is a real pain.  The === and =/= are just to maintain the idea that if "=?=" means "is it equal, I was hoping in context that in similar layout that "===" means 'yes, it is" and "$=\ne =$ means "no, it is not".  But with $\overset ?=$ that isn't really nesc.

Comment: MathJax Griping:  so learning of \overset I figured a checkmark over the = sign would be good.  So I did \overset \check = ... and got a "missing argument for check" error.  google search and I find that \checkmark is $\checkmark$.  So now I wonder, what is check and what the argments for check are suppose to be.  Anyway $\overset \checkmark =$ is kind of cool looking.

Answer (score 8):

The standard way to solve equations with square roots is to use this rule:
$$ \sqrt A=B\iff (A=B^2\quad\textbf{and}\quad B\ge 0). $$
So here you obtain
$$\sqrt{x-2}=x-4\iff x-2=x^2-8x+16\;\text{and}\; x\ge 4\iff(x-3)(x-6)=0\;\text{and}\; x\ge 4,$$
which shows there's only one root: $6$.

Comment: Why can't B be less than zero?

Comment: Also, where did u get x ≥ 4?

Comment: Because, by convention, the symbol $\sqrt{\text{positive number}}$ denotes, of the two square roots of a positive number, the positive root. $x\ge4$ comes from $B=x-4 \ge 0$.

Comment: The brave anonymous down-voter struck again!

Comment: Really, what's going on is $$ \sqrt A=B => A=B^2\quad. $$ So once we solve the second equation, we test them in the first equation to see if they're valid.

Comment: Sure but I mention an *equivalence* which every well-bred young people should know. How will you do when the roots do not have  a simple expression, or depend on a  parameter?

Answer (score 4):

The square root sign over a real number always denotes just the nonnegative square root. There's no $\pm$. If you square an equation with a square root in it you run the risk of allowing an extraneous solution.

In this example, $\sqrt{3-2} = 1 \ne 3-4$ .

There are many questions on this site with this answer, It was just easier for me to write it than to find them.

Answer (score 2):

You factored it correctly, but your mistake is considering both roots of $x$. When we say $\sqrt{x}$, we refer to the *principal root* of $x$; that is, the $positive$ square root of $x$  (issue in red, corrections in blue):

**For 3:**
$\sqrt {3-2} = 3-4$
$\sqrt {1} = \color{red}{±}1$ 
$\color{blue}{\sqrt {1} = -1}$
$\color{blue}{1 = -1 \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \text{false; not in solution set}}$

**For 6:**
$\sqrt {6-2} = 6-4$
$\sqrt {4} = \color{red}{±}2$
$\color{blue}{\sqrt {4} = 2}$
$\color{blue}{2 = 2 \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \text{true; in solution set}}$

The extraneous solution $x=3$ was brought about when you squared the radical, because squaring removes the restriction that $\sqrt{u} \geq 0$.

Comment: To be more precise, squaring the equation removes the condition $x-4\geq0$, or $x\geq4$